# Show that for any integer $r>1$ there exists an $r-$regular graph of order $2r$ and diameter 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

Show that for any integer $r> 1$ there exists an $r-$regular graph of order $2r$ and diameter $2$.

As it is a problem of existence, we should show how this graph is built ... or something like that.

Since the diameter is $2$, then the maximum distance must be $2$. Doing some examples, this is true. If the number of vertices is greater than $2r$, the diameter is greater than $2$. On the contrary, if the number of vertices is less than $2r$, the diameter is less than $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Your graph is the complete bipartite graph $K_{r, r}.$

Comment: Okay. One way to justify what you are saying would be to show that all bipartite graphs, $K_ {m, n}$, of diameter 2 are those such that $ m + n \geq 3 $ ... ???

Comment: @Gabriela No. The way to justify it is to check that $K_{r, r}$ has degree $r,$ order $2r$ and diameter $2.$ Can you do all/any of these?

Comment: I have: as it is a bipartite graph, there are sets of the partition $ V_1 $ and $ V_2 $ such that $ | V_1 | = r = | V_2 | $, then $ | V (G) | = | V_1 | + | V_2 | = 2r $. As it is complete, the number of edges is $ r ^ 2 $ ... with this, it is not clear how to deduce that it has diameter 2 and degree r.

Comment: @Gabriela The diameter is $1$ because a vertex in $V_1$ and a vertex in $V_2$ are connected by a path of length $1$, while two vertices in the same $V_i$ are connected by a path of length $2$. It is $r$-regular because each vertex in $V_i$ has exactly $r$ neighbors, namely, the vertices in $V_{3-i}$.

Comment: No, because $diam G$ is $max_{u, v\in V(G)}d(u, v)$

Comment: @Gabriela You have to work a lot harder to understand the material.